# Printing int **x in GDB

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, gdb

I have an array (called board) of pointers which point to array.
I want to print it in normal way (which is pretty hard in GDB).

```
int col = 64, row = 2;
int **board = new int*[col];
for(int i = 0; i < col; i++)
    board[i] = new int[row];
```

I have tried following commands:

> `p *array@len` (the problem is it prints in hexadecimal values not as integer)
>
> `x/100w array` (It scrolls so much down that i cannot even see the values)
>
> `*(T (*)[N])p` (where p is array, T is type of array and N is size of it) [It just does not print accurate]

Comment: You should prefer C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). You are asking for trouble by coding this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to print it in normal way

Your best bet is to write a `print_board` routine, which you can then call from GDB.

> (which is pretty hard in GDB).

That's because *you* made it hard.

The problem is that your board, rather than being contiguous in memory (as is customary and would be trivial to print in GDB), is instead spread out in 64 separate chunks of 2 values each.

Since you are using C++, you'll be better off using a vector of vectors:

```
vector<vector<int>> board;
board.resize(col);
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
  board[i].resize(row);
}

(gdb) print board
$1 = std::vector of length 64, capacity 64 =
 {std::vector of length 2, capacity 2 = {0, 0},
  std::vector of length 2, capacity 2 = {0, 0},
  ...
```

P.S. When asking questions, it helps to show *actual* code. Your question has the wrong type for `board`, and mixes `board` with `array`.

**Update:**

> How can I do that (use `print_board` from GDB)?

Here is an example. Suppose your source looks like this:

```
 1  #include <stdio.h>
 2  
 3  int main()
 4  {
 5    int col = 16, row = 2;
 6    int **board = new int*[col];
 7  
 8    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
 9      board[i] = new int[row];
10    }
11  
12    // Initialize elements to something interesting, so we can see them
13    // printed.
14    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
15      for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
16        board[i][j] = 100*i + j;
17  
18    return 0;
19  }
20  
21  void print_board(int **board, int col, int row)
22  {
23    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
24      for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
25        printf("\t%d", board[i][j]);
26      }
27      printf("\n");
28    }
29  }
```

Then, using GDB:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) break 18
(gdb) run

Breakpoint 2, main () at t.cc:18
18    return 0;

(gdb) call print_board(board, col, row)
    0   100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000    1100    1200    1300    1400    1500
    1   101 201 301 401 501 601 701 801 901 1001    1101    1201    1301    1401    1501
```

voilà

Comment: The vector of vectors shares the problem you identified of not being contiguous in memory

Comment: @M.M That's true, but vector pretty-printer solves *that* problem.

Comment: Actually, this answer is not helping at all. I did not say how can i print "vector of vectors". I tried print_board, and that command is not found.

Comment: @Siliproksi You are *supposed* to implement `print_board` command yourself (in your own code).

Comment: @EmployedRussian And than i can use it as command in GDB? How can i do that?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Well now its definitely a helpful answer (after the update). This is certainly the best solution for this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136268/discussion-between-siliproksi-and-employed-russian).